# 403 error in Google App Engine with staticdir

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine, http-status-codes, http-status-code-403

For some reason I can't get static_dir to work. In my app.ymal I have:

```
-   url: /ui
    static_dir: ui

-   url: /dump
    static_dir: dump
```

Loading static files from /ui works (i.e /ui/images/logo.png). But when I try to access something from /dumo I just get:

```
INFO     2009-11-12 14:03:55,497 dev_appserver.py:3034] "GET /dump/kaxas.zip HTTP/1.1" 403 -
```

If I change the name of the zip-file to something else it returns a 404 error. So in someway it finds the file.

On the server the files have the same owner and group, and the same rights (chmod 755).

I'm running dev_appserver on a linux server.

Any ideas?

..fredrik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP 403 code is usually returned by GAE for quota problems, read http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html

I think your zip file is more than 1 MB, and I have read it doesn't allow such big zip files. Try with a smaller file to make sure dump is working, I think it will work.

Comment: Yes, the 1MB limit is also described here: http://aralbalkan.com/1434
Apparently the GAE documentation is not very clear in describing the file limit.

Comment: Is there any way to raise the limit when running gae locally?

Comment: Also tested with a smaller file. Worked. Thanks.

Comment: The limit is now 10MB for static files and requests/responses, not 1MB.